# Adding multiple annotation to map

Tags: ios, mapkit

```
-(void)setLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion myregion;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;

    center.latitude=Nashik_Latitude;
    center.longitude=Nashik_Longitude;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=the_span;
    span.longitudeDelta=the_span;

    myregion.center=center;
    myregion.span=span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:myregion animated:YES];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Annotation *myann;
    for (APIElement *element in feedsFromRoot)
    {
        myann=[[Annotation alloc]init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[element.strlat doubleValue];
        coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[element.strlong doubleValue];
        location.latitude=coord.latitude;
        location.longitude=coord.longitude;
        myann.coordinate=location;
        myann.title=element.strName;
        myann.subtitle=element.strVicinity;
        [locations addObject:myann];
    }
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
}
```

I want to add multiple annotations which are stored in array and  have written following code but it is not showing any annotation. Please point out the mistake.

I have read latitude and longitude from `feedsFromRoot` array. Data is fetched properly but  annotations are still missing on the map. Is the written code is in right form or should I do any modification?

Data is gathered by JSOn parsing and is stored in feedsFromRoot array.

Comment: `coord.longitude` is being set to `strlat` (shouldn't it be `strlong`).  Same problem with `coord.latitude`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code... You should add new Annotation object in every iteration .

```
-(void)setLocation
{

    MKCoordinateRegion myregion;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;

    center.latitude=Nashik_Latitude;
    center.longitude=Nashik_Longitude;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=the_span;
    span.longitudeDelta=the_span;

    myregion.center=center;
    myregion.span=span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:myregion animated:YES];


    for (APIElement *element in feedsFromRoot)
    {
        Annotation *myann=[[Annotation alloc]init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[element.strlat doubleValue];
        coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[element.strlong doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude=coord.latitude;
        location.longitude=coord.longitude;
        myann.coordinate=location;
        myann.title=element.strName;
        myann.subtitle=element.strVicinity;
        [locations addObject:myann];
    }
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
}
```

Comment: The code in the question _is_ creating a new object (alloc+init) in every iteration.  Only the _declaration_ of the variable is outside which is ok.

Comment: It is actually changing properties of same object in every iteration. that could be a problem.

Comment: No, a new object is created at each iteration, it is added to an array which retains it.  At the next iteration, a new object is created which does not modify the previous ones.  A declaration alone like `Annotation *myann;` does not create an instance of an object.